# include a loading page in between registration and thank you pages

Tags: javascript, php, loading, google-email-settings-api

Hi i would like to add a loading or waiting page after form submission. I've registration page and thank you page, and have to send out a registration email before showing the thank you page. Email sending will takes around 2 min. So if i can add a loading/waiting page after submit the registration page and before thank you page, that will help to avoid re-submission from users side.

How can i add this page using javascript/php/jquery? Any simple demo?

Comment: My recommendation is to use a Jquery modal to show a spinner icon and disable all page interaction. The modal would become active when you click the submit button.

Comment: Just make a redirect with a loading gif. People don't need to wait, but it's better for understanding that the website is busy working on their product e.g.

Answer (score 0):

From Registrationpage you navigate to your "Waiting Page" and have this Tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120; URL=http://YOUR_THANK_YOU_PAGE">
```

This will redirect to YOUR_THANK_YOU_PAGE after 120 Secounds. no PHP, JS, jQuery needed